# How to block website using SQUID server

Tags: debian, squid

I am using squid server in my Debian server, I want to block some websites in my system and I followed all the procedures for this but there is no result.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to do some changes in squid.conf and here are the steps:

- open this file /etc/squid3/squid.conf
- add these lines:

  ```
  acl bad_url dstdomain "/etc/squid3/bad-sites.acl"
  http_access deny bad_url
  ```
- then go to /etc/squid3/bad-sites.acl and add domains with this format

  ```
  .google.com
  .msn.com
  .app.facebook.com
  ```

Comment: Adding the rules at the end of squid.conf file won't work. Add at appropriate position. Look for message like "INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS"

Comment: Just a note: `.google.com` also blocks `google.com`. Don't try to add both, or squid gives an error.

Comment: I've copy and past your config but it does not work did I miss something ? (please notice that I'm trying this prox for the first time right now ) ENV: Ubuntu 16.04 Squid3

Comment: It took me a while to figure that I need to restart the proxy service to have the config rules applied in Windows.

Comment: I was able to block facebook.com from browser in phone, but when I use facebook app it was able to access facebook, why is that ?

Answer (score 10):

You can also do by following changes in squid.conf

```
acl toblock dstdomain .facebook.com .google.com
http_access deny toblock
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using all this Just go to the terminal press (window-button+T)
then type

> sudo gedit /etc/hosts

then select your ip address and write the name of the site you want to block

```
127.0.0.1    localhost blockme.example.com
```

this will route all requests to that domain to your IP address instead

Answer (score 0):

search in squid.cong the line "acl CONNECT method CONNECT" after it insert the acl that you would like to block for exemple i would like to block facebook so :

```
acl FACEBOOK url_regex -i *.facebook.com*
```

the url_regex will help to block any url that contain facebook.com
now search the line

"# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS" in squid config
insert after it http_access deny <the_name_you_gave_to_your_act> in our exemple

```
http_access deny FACEBOOK
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).